# c clock() in different OS

Tags: c, clock

i need a 60HZ timer (16.6 ms trigger once)

it work well in windows(mingw gcc) but not in liunx(gcc)

can anyone help me abust this? THX

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>t
#define PRE_MS CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000
int main()
{
    clock_t pre = clock();
    int cnt = 0;
    printf("CLOCKS_PER_SEC = %d\n", CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    while (1)
    {
        clock_t diff = clock() - pre;
        if (diff > 16 * PRE_MS)
        {
            cnt++;
            if (cnt > 60)
            {
                printf("%d\n", (int)pre);
                cnt = 0;
            }
            pre += diff;
        }
    }
}
```

- printf pre 1s in windows

```
CLOCKS_PER_SEC = 1000
1020
2058
3095
4132
5169
6206
7243
8280
9317
```

- printf pre 2s in linux

```
CLOCKS_PER_SEC = 1000000
1875000
3781250
5687500
7593750
9500000
11406250
13312500
15218750
```

Comment: Please don't change the code after an answer has been posted.

Comment: it's still cause that problem,i just want make my code more clean，your code seem work for me ,i'll check it later ,thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a misconception: 60 Hz is not 17 operations per second but 60.

Second the period check is reading `clock()` twice and discarding any time interval for `printf()` to be called. AFAIK the `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is larger on Linux than Windows systems, so there is more chance that you are 'throwing away' clock ticks. Read the `clock()` *once*, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long long tickcount = 0;
    clock_t baseticks = clock();    
    while (tickcount < 180) {           // for 3 seconds
        tickcount++;
        clock_t nexttick = (clock_t) (baseticks + tickcount * CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 60);
        while(clock() < nexttick) {}    // wait
        printf("Tick %llu\n", tickcount);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code works from the total elapsed time, so any intervals that are not an exact number of clock ticks are averaged out (instead of a cumulative rounding-off error).

At some point the value from `clock()` will overflow/wrap, so a real implementation that runs for any length of time will have to take care of this.